# Increasing a value with time in a time series

Tags: python, numpy, time-series

In my code below, I wish to have the value of `gamma` increase from 0.4, to 0.8, lets say linearly at first, in small increments. I want this to go up as time `t` goes up, so by the time the time series is over, `gamma` is 0.8. Is it possible to do this within this ODE system?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



# Total population, N.
N = 1
# Initial number of infected and recovered individuals, I0 and R0.
I0, R0 = 0.001, 0
# Everyone else, S0, is susceptible to infection initially.
U0 = N - I0 - R0
J0 = I0
Lf0, Ls0 = 0, 0
# Contact rate, beta, and mean recovery rate, gamma, (in 1/days).
beta, gamma = 8, 0.4
int_gamma = np.linspace(0.4, 0.8, 1000+1)
mu, muTB, sigma, rho = 1/80, 1/6, 1/6, 0.03
u, v, w = 0.88, 0.083, 0.0006
t = np.linspace(0, 1000, 1000+1)

# The SIR model differential equations.
def deriv(y, t, N, beta, gamma, mu, muTB, sigma, rho, u, v, w):
    U, Lf, Ls, I, R, cInc = y
    b = (mu * (U + Lf + Ls + R)) + (muTB * I)
    lamda = beta * I
    clamda = 0.2 * lamda
    dU = b - ((lamda + mu) * U)
    dLf = (lamda*U) + ((clamda)*(Ls + R)) - ((u + v + mu) * Lf)
    dLs = (u * Lf) - ((w + clamda + mu) * Ls)
    dI = w*Ls + v*Lf - ((gamma + muTB + sigma) * I) + (rho * R)
    dR = ((gamma + sigma) * I) - ((rho + clamda + mu) * R)
    cI = w*Ls + v*Lf + (rho * R)
    return dU, dLf, dLs, dI, dR, cI


# Integrate the SIR equations over the time grid, t.
solve = odeint(deriv, (U0, Lf0, Ls0, I0, R0, J0), t, args=(N, beta, gamma, mu, muTB, sigma, rho, u, v, w))
U, Lf, Ls, I, R, cInc = solve.T
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `np.geomspace` which may help.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.geomspace( 0.4, 0.8, num = 10 )
arr
# array([0.4       , 0.4320239 , 0.46661162, 0.50396842, 0.544316, 
#        0.5878938 , 0.63496042, 0.68579519, 0.74069977, 0.8       ])
np.diff( arr )
# array([0.0320239 , 0.03458772, 0.0373568 , 0.04034758, 0.0435778 ,
#        0.04706662, 0.05083477, 0.05490458, 0.05930023])
```

Or compound two linspaces

```
x = 1.5
arr = np.linspace( 0.4, 0.8/x, num = 10 ) * np.linspace( 1, x, num = 10 )
arr
# array([0.4       , 0.43786008, 0.47736626, 0.51851852, 0.56131687,
#        0.60576132, 0.65185185, 0.69958848, 0.74897119, 0.8       ])

np.diff( arr )  
# array([0.03786008, 0.03950617, 0.04115226, 0.04279835, 0.04444444,
#        0.04609053, 0.04773663, 0.04938272, 0.05102881])
```

Different values of x change the acceleration in the result.